# Replace String with its corresponding value when it matches a key in a dict key:value pair

Tags: python, key-value

For example, the dictionary may be

```
{'Cat': 'Dog', 'Bird': 'Mouse'}
```

And when the user input
'There is a cat'
The output would be
'There is a dog'

I tried replacing it with the value but it clearly doesn't work with dict.
Please help.

Comment: You should show what you've tried and explain what "doesn't work" means

Answer (score 3):

given a pair of `<key:value>`, you just need to access the `dict` in the `key` index to get the `value`:

```
d = {'Cat': 'Dog', 'Bird': 'Mouse'}
user_input = 'There is a cat'
# use split() to split string into words
# use [-1] to get last word ('cat')
#print(d[user_input.split()[-1]]) # would fail, since "cat" isn't inside the dict
user_input = 'There is a Cat'
print("There is a", d[user_input.split()[-1]]) # This time it would work. Output "There is a Dog"
```

Answer (score 2):

OR `''.join` joining a string split woth dictionary get method:

```
d = {'Cat': 'Dog', 'Bird': 'Mouse'}
s='There is a cat'
s2=' '.join(d.get(i.title(),i) for i in s.split())
print(s2)
```

Output:

```
There is a Dog
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the keys inside `dict` and check with the given input. If it is present you can replace it with the corresponding value.

```
d = {'Cat': 'Dog', 'Bird': 'Mouse'}
inp = 'There is a Cat'

for key,value in d.items():
  if key in inp:
    inp = inp.replace(key,value)

print(inp)
'There is a Dog'
```

Please note that conditionals are case-sensitive. You can convert strings to same case with `str.lower()` if you are looking for case-insensitive checks.

Comment: If you use 'There is a Catalogue', you get 'There is a Dogalogue'. Only splitting the words and go through each of them surely works. I still did not know about this, perhaps it helps somewhere else, that is why no downvote nor upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into words, replace each word with the the corresponding value in the dict if the word is an index, and then join the words into a string:

```
d = {'Cat': 'Dog', 'Bird': 'Mouse'}
s = 'There is a Cat'
print(' '.join(d.get(w, w) for w in s.split()))
```

This outputs:

```
There is a Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner.

```
d = {'cat': 'dog', 'bird': 'mouse'}
input_ = 'There is a cat'
output = ' '.join([x if x not in d else d[x] for x in input_.split()])

>> print (output)
>> There is a dog
```

***BREAK DOWN***

`input_.split()` splits the input into a list of words.

`[ ]` create a new list

`for x in input_.split()` for every word in the input string

`x if x not in d` add all the words that can't be found in dict.

`else d[x]` for any word that is found in dic, instead of adding the word, add the according value from the dict

`' '.join([])` join all the words in the list with a space between each word.